# Building Qt for WinRT using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, qt, windows-runtime

I downloaded the Qt for Windows Runtime Technology Preview from this location:

http://download.qt-project.org/development_releases/qt/winrt-tp/

When I try to build it using the instructions mentioned [here](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/12/12/qt-for-windows-runtime-technology-preview-released/?utm_source=rssutm_medium=rssutm_campaign=qt-for-windows-runtime-technology-preview-released), I eventually run into the following error:

```
        win_flex --noline --nounistd --outfile=Tokenizer.cpp ..\..\..\..\3rdparty\angle\src\compiler\preprocessor\Tokenizer.l
'win_flex' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'win_flex' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/

Comment: installed it.  added it to the path, rebuilt, still fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed win_flex from http://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/

Then in my source, I went to the directory:
.....\qtbase-opensource-src-5.3.0-WinRT-TP\qtbase-opensource-src-5.3.0-WinRT-TP\src\angle\src\compiler\preprocessor

and changed both Makefile.debug and Makefile.release to make sure that "win_flex" and "bison" commands are executed with their full paths specified from their install directories.  This fixed the above mentioned problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
When you extract the sources, it will have a directory structure like this:

.....\qtbase-opensource-src-5.3.0-WinRT-TP\qtbase-opensource-src-5.3.0-WinRT-TP\bin

.....\qtbase-opensource-src-5.3.0-WinRT-TP\qtbase-opensource-src-5.3.0-WinRT-TP\src

The compilation script just looking for win_flex in a directory named gnuwin32.
This directory and its content can be found at https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt5/source/4c925babf9e7f516479a0e418e9b3f509d3cd4b7:gnuwin32 or in the complete Qt5-Sources (WinRT Technology Preview Sources are just a subset).
Copy this directory to the path, then it should look like this:

.....\qtbase-opensource-src-5.3.0-WinRT-TP\qtbase-opensource-src-5.3.0-WinRT-TP\bin

.....\qtbase-opensource-src-5.3.0-WinRT-TP\qtbase-opensource-src-5.3.0-WinRT-TP\src

.....\qtbase-opensource-src-5.3.0-WinRT-TP\gnuwin32\

NOTE 1: Downloading win_flex from sourceforge or add it to the PATH variable does not work! Compilation script searching win_flex hard-coded in the gnuwin32 directory!

NOTE 2: I posted a comment on the official blog post, maybe the guys from Digia will fix the WinRT-TP-Source-Package soon...

Comment: keeping that directory in that location didnt help me either